# Redistribution of C# dll to be used by VB6

Tags: .net, vb6, interop, tlb

We create a C# dll to be used with VB6 (ComVisible = true, Register for COM Interop). 
In VB6 on developper PC, everything is working OK.

We try to redistribute it on another PC. We are aware that we should regenerate the **tlb** file by using the following command line on a **x64** Windows

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe C:\CLYO\Clyo.Interfaces.dll /tlb:C:\CLYO\Clyo.Interfaces.tlb
```

We also try with **codebase**

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe C:\CLYO\Clyo.Interfaces.dll /tlb:C:\CLYO\Clyo.Interfaces.tlb /codebase
```

but we continue to get `Error 429 - ActiveX component can't create object`

**Any Idea?**

Note: Our C# code use a different Guid for each class, and interface

```
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
[Guid("EC8D67C4-0B8B-4692-9CA4-8657805D9B40")]
public interface IRestoFlash
{
    ...
}

[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[Guid("D068F8B5-AAC8-48D2-BEED-4505DBC802D6")]
[ProgId("Clyo_Interfaces.RestoFlash")]
public class RestoFlash:IRestoFlash 
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the path to Regasm x32 resolves the problem ...

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe 
                                 ^^ (without 64)
```